# Jquery not setting element ID when using .button()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gevponph/2/). It's just changing the id and text of the button when you change tab and then there when you click on them it just displays an alert.

I know the code works because before you change tab it works as expected. However when you change tab the id of the button is set but the click event doesn't fire.

#### HTML

```
<div id="lineitems">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="topnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#allocate">Awaiting Allocation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#not-issued">Awaiting Issued</a></li>
            <li><a href="#issued">Issued</a></li>
            <span id="button-container">
            <button id='allocate-parts' type='button' class="allocate">Allocate Selected Parts</button>
            </span>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="allocate">Allocate tab</div>
<div id="not-issued">Awaiting Issued tab</div>
<div id="issued">Issued Items</div>
```

#### Jquery

```
$( "#lineitems" ).tabs();
$('button').button();

        $("#lineitems").tabs({
      activate: function (event, ui) {
        issued = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); //Get newly selected tab
        
        //alert("tabs "+issued);
        switch(issued) {
            case "allocate": var buttonText = "<button type='button' id='allocate-parts'>Allocate Selected Parts</button>"; $('#joblist').removeAttr("disabled"); $('button').prop('id','allocate-parts');
                break;
            case "not-issued": var buttonText = "<button type='button' id='issue-parts'>Issue Selected Parts</button>"; $('#joblist').removeAttr("disabled"); $('button').prop('id','issue-parts');
                break;
            case "issued": var buttonText = "<button type='button'>Return Selected Parts</button>"; $('#joblist').removeAttr("disabled");
            
        } //End of switch
          
     $('#button-container').html(buttonText);
     $('button').button();
          
      }
        });
    
          
$('#allocate-parts').click(function() {
   alert("Parts Allocated");
});
          
$('#issue-parts').click(function() {
   alert("Parts Issued");
});
```

On tab change I have tried changing the id in the HTML and by using `$('button').prop('id','issue-parts')`. But neither of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the click events for the buttons as below and try

```
$(document).on("click","#allocate-parts",function() {
   alert("Parts Allocated");
});

$(document).on("click","#issue-parts",function() {
   alert("Parts Issued");
});
```

If still it doesn't works then update your code as

```
//alert("tabs "+issued);
        switch(issued) {
            case "allocate": var buttonText = "<button id='allocate-parts' type='button'>Allocate Selected Parts</button>"; 
                break;
            case "not-issued": var buttonText = "<button id='issue-parts' type='button'>Issue Selected Parts</button>";
                break;
            case "issued": var buttonText = "<button type='button'>Return Selected Parts</button>";

        } //End of switch

     $('#button-container').empty();
     $('#button-container').html(buttonText);
```

This will definitely work.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this, it's working. I'm just curious why mine didn't. isn't `$(document).on("click","#allocate-parts",function() {` the same as  `$('#allocate-parts').click(function() {`

Comment: no dear, they are quite different bcos `$('#allocate-parts').click(function()` will fire only if the element was already present in DOM while the event was bound, but `$(document).on("click","#allocate-parts",function()` would work for dynamically generated element.. i.e. it will find the element in DOM and attach the event to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "delegate" method like:

```
$(document).delegate('#allocate-parts',"click",function() {
   alert("Parts Allocated");
});
```

**OR**
You have to use "on" method like:

```
$(document).on("click",'#issued-parts',function() {
   alert("Parts Issued");
});
```

Please see the updated fiddle: **[JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/gevponph/32/)**

Because you are changing the id of button at runtime, you need to delegate the method to document; So the event can be triggered on click.

And one more thing is that you have to define button id in Button tag string:

```
<button type='button' id='issued-parts'>Return Selected Parts</button>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, then there are a few thing you need to consider.

1. You are creating dynamic elements so you need to delegate events on document or on an existing element.
2. span is not a right element inside ul. so move it out.
3. You need to call $('button').button() after new button is appended to container.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gevponph/29/):

JS:

```
$( "#lineitems" ).tabs();

$('button').button();

        $("#lineitems").tabs({
      activate: function (event, ui) {
        issued = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); //Get newly selected tab
        var buttonText = "";
        //alert("tabs "+issued);
        switch(issued) {
        case "allocate":  buttonText = "<button id='allocate-parts'  type='button'>Allocate Selected Parts</button>";           $(buttonText).attr('id','allocate-parts');
                break;
            case "not-issued":  buttonText = "<button id='issue-parts' type='button'>Issue Selected Parts</button>"; 
                break;
            case "issued":  buttonText = $("<button id='return-parts' type='button'>Return Selected Parts</button>");


        } //End of switch

        $('#button-container').empty().append(buttonText);
        $('button').button();

      }
        });

$(document).on('click','#allocate-parts',function() {
   alert("Parts Allocated");
});

$(document).on('click','#issue-parts',function() {
   alert("Parts Issued");
});


$(document).on('click','#return-parts',function() {
   alert("Return Parts");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lineitems">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="topnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#allocate">Awaiting Allocation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#not-issued">Awaiting Issued</a></li>
            <li><a href="#issued">Issued</a></li>
          </ul>
            <span id="button-container">
            <button id='allocate-parts' type='button' class="allocate">Allocate Selected Parts</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="allocate">Allocate tab</div>
    <div id="not-issued">Awaiting Issued tab</div>
    <div id="issued">Issued Items</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE -

```
<div id="lineitems">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <div id="topnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#allocate">Awaiting Allocation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#not-issued">Awaiting Issued</a></li>
            <li><a href="#issued">Issued</a></li>
            <span id="button-container">
            <button id='allocate-parts' type='button' class="allocate">Allocate Selected Parts</button>
            </span>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="allocate">Allocate tab</div>
    <div id="not-issued">Awaiting Issued tab</div>
    <div id="issued">Issued Items</div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code -

```
$( "#lineitems" ).tabs();
$('button').button();

        $("#lineitems").tabs({
      activate: function (event, ui) {
        issued = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); //Get newly selected tab
        switch(issued) {
            case "allocate": var buttonText = "Allocate Selected Parts";var id ="allocate-parts";
                break;
            case "not-issued": var buttonText = "Issue Selected Parts";
                var id ="not-issue-parts";
                break;
            case "issued": var buttonText = "Return Selected Parts";
                var id ="issue-parts";

        } //End of switch

     $('#button-container .ui-button span.ui-button-text').html(buttonText);
         $('#button-container .ui-button').attr('id', id);
      }
        });

$(document).on('click','#allocate-parts', function() {
   alert("Parts Allocated");
});

$(document).on('click','#issue-parts',function() {
   alert("Parts Issued");
});

$(document).on('click','#not-issue-parts',function() {
   alert("Parts Not Issued");
});
```

JSFiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/fhob3Lw1/